# clang(not clangcc) is not supported by coverity8

Tags: c++, linux, coverity

I am using coverity to analyze my code.
but when I configured cov, got an error.

```
> cov-configure --config
> /home/opt/coverity/Coverity/cov-admin/cov-conf/config/coverity_config_armcc.xml
> --comptype clang --compiler ****** --template
```

got an error:

```
Unknown compiler type clang
The only supported compiler types are:
******
```

So I'm doubt that if coverity supports clang compiler, or I have done something wrong.

The coverity version is 8.

BRs.

Comment: You should talk to the Coverity sales reps and not ask here.  You'll get better response by talking to them.  I always do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverity 8 definitely supports Clang. The issue is you're using `--comptype clang` - the comptype for Clang is `--comptype clangcc` (note the extra cc).

If you're in doubt, `cov-configure --list-compiler-types` is a good place to start, as is the documentation.

Note that so long as your Clang binary has the default name, `cov-configure --clang` should be all you need. Otherwise I strongly recommend you use `--template` on your `cov-configure` command line as well, as the CIT implementation for Clang makes heavy usage of "required" arguments and you're unlikely to get a successful capture of your build without using `--template`.

Comment: Thx for your analysis, that solves my problem.Thx a lot.